# How many combinations can be made from this scenario?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I know there are similar questions posted on here, but since their are basically infinite problems like this, Idk how to apply them in certain situations. I have added the question and what I believe to be the answers, but I'm unsure of a few of them if someone could please provide feedback. Thanks!!

**Scenario:** Determine the number of ways to select 6 animals from a a variety of 20 (different) animals:

1.) If all 6 selected are of different types

$\binom{20}{6}$

2.) If half of them are of one type and the other half of another type

$\binom{20}{1} + \binom{19}{1}$?

3.) If all are the same

$\binom{20}{1}$?

4.) If no conditions are applied

$\binom{20}{6}$?

*note: order does not matter

Thanks again!

Comment: Are there $20$ different **types** of animal? And are there at least $6$ of each type? And are any two zebras indistinguishable?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeah the question is very vague. I believe it's saying that the TOTAL number of animals is unknown/infinite, but there are 20 different types of "unlimited" animals (of that type). The 4 sub questions are a bit more specific. But for each sub question, we WANT 6 animals. I'm assuming all of the animals of a type are equivalent. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** We choose 6 animals out of 20, and we don't care about the order. (If someone asks you about the six animals you've selected, he/she won't care if the zebras or the elephants were selected first.). $\binom{20}{6}$

**(2)** We have to choose two types of animals. Again, which one we choose first doesn't matter: $\binom{20}{2}$

**(3)** They are all the same (of one type): $\binom{20}{1} = 20$ different options.

**(4)** There are several different cases here. We might have just one type of animal, for example six zebras. Another way could be that we have zebras and horses, 3 of each. Or 4 zebras and 2 horses. Or in general up to 6 types of animals, but exactly 6 animals chosen in total.

There were 20 different types of animals. If we call the number of different animals that we choose $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{20}$, and there have to be 6 in total, we can say:

$$x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{20} = 6$$

Since we cannot select a negative amount of one type, we have $x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0, \dots$ etc. This type of problem is solved with the very common combinatorial tool commonly called [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), and the solution is:

$$\binom{20+6-1}{6-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

We assume that there are $20$ different **types** of animal, that there are at least $6$ animals of each type, and that animals of the same type, such as agoutis, are indistinguishable.

1) We need to choose $6$ distinct types. There are $\binom{20}{6}$ ways to do that.

2)  We need to choose $2$ distinct types from the $20$.

3)  We need to choose $1$ type. Easy!

4)  This one is substantially harder! List the types of animal alphabetically. Now consider the equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{20}=6$. We claim that there is a one-to-one correspondence between solutions of this equation in non-negative integers and choices of animals. If we choose $a_i$ animals of type $i$, that corresponds to the solution $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{20}=6$.

Finding the number of solutions of this equation is a standard "Stars and Bars" problem (please see wikipedia). There are $\binom{20+6-1}{6-1}$ solutions.

Comment: 1. Is different types. Isn't C(20,6) just "any 6" of the 20?

Comment: Yes, different types means there will be $6$ types, and therefore $1$ animal o each type. So once we have chosen the $6$ types from $20$, which can be done in $\binom{20}{5}$ ways, we have no further freedom.